# Randomization test with constraints

Tags: test-management, test-automation-framework

My current project is written in **C++**. It takes a certain `config` file to do various work. There are a large number of parameters inside the `config`. I would like to do *randomization test* for those inputs. What I would like to achieve is following:

1. For each parameters, I do uniformly randomization with its own constraints.
2. The whole testing sample would be drawn uniformly from whole parameter space.

I am new to software testing. What I would like to achieve is something like **UVM** does for hardware verification. I am wondering if there is any framework for this. **Python** is preferred.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that came to my mind was [Spotify's Model-Based Testing](https://www.cs.tut.fi/tapahtumat/testaus12/kalvot/Karl_ta.pdf), it doesn't describe your case exactly but looks like you can use a similar method.

Build a model of your constraints and let a tool run through the combinations.

Also try and evaluate Microsoft's [PICT tool](https://github.com/Microsoft/pict) as the source for your constraints model description, it has the added benefit that if some parameters are known to be independent of each other the tool will help you decrease the number of tests needed.